# Trouble setting and adding array values javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, addition, assign

I want to give each check box an integer value and then if the box is checked add the values and display the total in a text box with the ID="options".  So far the code is not sending a value to the desired location.  Any instruction on how to improve the code would be helpful. Thank you.

```
<html>
<body>

<form id="registration" name="registration">
<input name="opt1" value="5" type="checkbox"> Breakfast ($5)
<input name="opt2" value="10" type="checkbox"> Lunch ($10)
<input name="opt3" checked="checked" value="0" type="checkbox"> Happy Hour (free!)
<input id="options" name="options" type="text">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<script>

function getOptions() {

    var form = document.getElementById("registration"),
        inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input"),
        result = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type === "checkbox" && inputs[i].checked) {
            result += inputs[i].value;
            document.getElementById("options").value = result;
        }
    }
}

getOptions();

</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean "improve"? Does the current code have the desired effect or not?

Comment: Right now it does nothing.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after `var i = 0` in the `for loop`

Comment: I added the semicolon. Now it just displays 00 in the desired location, but nothing happens when i check the boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to attach [onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event handlers to the checkboxes as shown below. And you should parse `inputs[i].value` to a number using [parseFloat()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) before adding it to `result`.

```
var form = document.getElementById("registration"),
    inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input");

function getOptions() {
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type === "checkbox" && inputs[i].checked) {
            result += parseFloat(inputs[i].value);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("options").value = result;
}

for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type === "checkbox") {
        inputs[i].onchange = function () {
            getOptions();
        }
    }
}

getOptions();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nr6r2183/3/)

Comment: Just curious if I can consolidate the second for loop by using forEach() after the first for loop.  I need to make the code so that the grand total is updated every time a value changes, so I want to make the getOptions() function more succinct. Is it possible to use forEach() to achieve the same result as the second "for" loop?

Comment: Yes, you can use `forEach()` instead of `for` loop, but you must convert the input NodeList to an array like so `Array.prototype.slice.call(form.getElementsByTagName("input"))`. That's because NodeLists are array-like but don't feature many of the methods provided by the Array, like forEach, map, filter, etc.
Also take note that `forEach()` is considerably slower than `for` loop.
I've created this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6t6jcsg/1/) that using `forEach()`.

Comment: Thanks frosdqy.  I was able to get it to work using the original "for" loop.